# Отправка сообщения с сервера на Java в группе Telegram

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Приветы.

На сайте site.ru пользователь пишет сообщение в форму обратной связи. Я это сообщение отправляю на почту. Теперь хочу дублировать его и в группу Телеграм, в которую входят несколько человек, чтобы все могли читать что пишут.

Как это сделать, подскажите! Сервер на Java.
Спасибо.

Comment: Ну без API Телеграма никак. Посмотри на его API,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень просто!

1) Создаётся бот через приложение (надо добавить в чат **@BotFather**)

2) Создаётся **открытая** группа.

3) Бот добавляется в группу.

4) Бот отправляет сообщение в группу через браузер **по названию группы**

5) В ответе необходимо найти id группы

6) Изменяем группу на private

7) Бот отправляет сообщение в группу **по id** по URL

Пример запроса:

```
https://api.telegram.org/<id бота>/sendMessage?chat_id=<id чата>&text=мой текст
```